# How to call NSThread repeatedly?

Tags: iphone, xml, nsthread

I am working on an application where i have to call a thread repeatedly. In that thread we have to parse an XML  and i have to get updated data  from that xml. now please guide me how to call that thread repeatedly? if my thread is in working and my code calls it again, then i think it will have a crash on it.

Comment: Can you briefly describe what you're trying to do?  Is it possible that you shouldn't be calling the thread completely but instead using something like GCD repeatedly call async work over shared data??

Comment: Infect i have to update score by getting data from an xml. in the order to get updated score i have to refredh the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the code into a new method

```
-(void) thisMethodWillRunAsASeparateThread
{
    //Threads need their own pool.
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    while (thisThreadShouldRun)
    {
        // run xml parsing code
    }
    [pool release];
}
```

and to start the thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(thisMethodWillRunAsASeparateThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Comment: you mean i have to run two threads? it will not be cause of crash?

Comment: You can run two threads without an app crashing. Your app _may_ crash if you don't properly apply mutual exclusion where necessary.

Comment: @Mashhadi: I thought instead of Parsing, Calling to web Service which fetches live data (here in case updated score) should be in thread. Just check weather connection is active or closed based on that give next call to service

Answer (score 0):

To call any code repeatedly you must NSTimer  like:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.10f target:self 

selector:@selector(methodName)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

you should to invalidate the timer after use. while if you wan to execute the code using background thread you must this code but this will not repeat multiple times.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(methodName:) toTarget:self withObject:objName,nil]];
```

Comment: if in this way it call my thread when my thread is already under process then?

Comment: you must used background thread

http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-keeping-the-ui-responsive-and-a-background-thread-pattern/